# Leaving values for options unevaluated in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm having some problems with writing a function that takes options. One of the option values is a function. I one to get at this value but keep it unevaluated. I tried every single thing I could possibly think of but nothing worked so far.

Basically, to illustrate this is what I tried:

```
SetAttributes[Foo, HoldRest];
Options[Foo] = {Blah -> None}

Foo[x_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[{blah},

        blah = OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, Blah, Hold];
        .
        .
        .
```

Then when I have:

```
func[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c;
```

I'd like to be able to call Foo with:

```
Foo[2, Blah -> func[1, 2, 3]]
```

And have the "blah" variable (inside Foo) to be unevaluated, i.e. blah = func[1, 2, 3].

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Edit:

For reasons that are too long to elaborate, I cannot use RuleDelayed (:>). I'm trying to write a function that will be in a package, used by other people that don't really know Mathematica, so they would have no clue what :> is. Using rules (->) for specifying options and their values is the standard way and they familiar with that.

So to further illustrate, let's say that I'm trying to write a number generator function that takes a function that generates the actual number as one of it's options:

```
Options[GenerateNumbers] = {GeneratorFunction -> None};

GenerateNumbers[n_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[{func},

        func = OptionValue[GeneratorFunction];
        Table[func, {n}]
    ]     
]
```

Now, if I called this function with values as follows:

```
GenerateNumbers[5, GeneratorFunction -> RandomReal[10]]
```

It would return a list of 5 numbers that are the same, since RandomReal[10] gets evaluated once and not at every iteration of Table. I want to prevent this. The problem is more complicated but it's along these lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use a name for the `OptionsPattern` and then wrap the captured sequence object with a `List` and an `Unevaluated`. A very minimal way of capturing the right-hand side for `Blah` is:

```
SetAttributes[Foo, HoldRest]; Options[Foo] = {Blah -> None};
Foo[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{blah},
  blah = OptionValue[Foo, Unevaluated[{opts}], Blah, Hold];
  blah]
```

Testing it out:

```
In[2]:= Foo[x, Blah -> (1 + 1)]
Out[2]= Hold[1 + 1]
```

Comment: One general problem with `Hold`-attributes and `OptionsPattern` is that options passed not directly but say as `Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts},Options[Foo]]` (or any other way which would require their evaluation) will not be matched by `OptionsPattern` in the presense of `Hold` - attributes (I mean, `HoldAll` and `HoldRest`). Of course, this is natural in this example, but  this requirement of options being only passed directly is very non-obvious and can puzzle the end-user of the function. I had this problem a few times with my own functions, and even that was quite puzzling.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use RuleDelayed?

```
Foo[2, Blah :> func[1, 2, 3]]
```

In this case `blah=Hold[func[1, 2, 3]]` as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of the options is a little strange. If you want to pass some expression wrapped in Hold, why not wrap it in Hold when passing, like `Blah->Hold[func[1,2,3]]`? Anyway, assuming this simple definition for `Foo`:

```
Foo[x_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
Module[{blah},
   blah = OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, Blah, Hold];
   blah
],
```

you can accomplish what you want by passing an option with `RuleDelayed` rather than `Rule`:

```
In[7]:= func[a_, b_, c_] := a + b + c;

In[8]:= Foo[2, Blah :> func[1, 2, 3]]

Out[8]= Hold[func[1, 2, 3]]
```

HTH

Edit:

If you don't want `Hold` wrapped around, here is one way to get rid of it:

```
In[25]:= 
ClearAll[setDelayedHeld];
SetAttributes[setDelayedHeld, HoldFirst];
setDelayedHeld[lhs_, Hold[rhs_]] := lhs := rhs

In[28]:= 
Clear[Foo];
Foo[x_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{blah},
   setDelayedHeld[blah, OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, Blah, Hold]];
   OwnValues[blah]]

In[30]:= Foo[2, Blah :> func[1, 2, 3]]

Out[30]= {HoldPattern[blah$1018] :> func[1, 2, 3]}
```

I return `OwnValues` for `blah` to show that it was assigned `func[1,2,3]` without evaluating the latter - if this is what you want.